# DevExpress. Выбрать строку в GridControl програмно

Tags: devexpress

Подскажите пожалуйста сабж. Обрыскал инет, но не нашёл прямого ответа на свой вопрос. Повсюду примеры только с GridView. Но у меня GridControl заполненый из массива объектов. Теперь у меня есть экземпляр одного из таких объектов. и я хочу установить фокус на строку грида с имеющемся у меня экземпляром.

Answer (score 2):

А чем вас не устраивают примеры с GridView, видимо вы не много не понимаете архитектуры этого грида, но я вам помогу. GridControl содержит коллекцию view. Если вы хотите найти главную view используйте GridControl.MainView property. Там вы можете вызвать метод LocateByValue и передать в него уникальное занчение для вашей строчки. Получив нужный индекс, другими словами RowHandle. Вы можете установить его в GridView.FocusedRowHandle свойство.

Почить документаци можно найдя её через поиск
https://search.devexpress.com/

А там конечно там сидит ватага ребят из суппорта, они вам в миг помогут пока вы триалите или есил купили лиценцзию.